# EXTBASE: Exception while property mapping at property path

Tags: model, typo3, extbase

When calling getter on AbstractValueObject object this error is shown:

> Exception while property mapping at property path
>   "":Creation of objects not allowed. To enable this, you
>   need to set the PropertyMappingConfiguration Value
>   "CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED" to TRUE

How to resolve this?

Comment: You're getting this error when calling the getter??? That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

In Your extension builder, model shoud be selected as Entity instead of Value Object.
Or in model class change class definition to extend AbstractEntity instead of AbstractValueObject

```
# change this line:
class MyClass extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractValueObject
# into this line:
class MyClass extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
```

Comment: This indeed solved the problem (had the same issue) - but the real problem still remains...

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to this issue without discarding ValueObject type: In the form viewhelper, one has to handover explicitly the UID of the AbstractValueObject:

I.e.

```
<f:for each="{colors}" as="color">
    <f:form.radio property="color" value="{color.uid}" />
</f:for>
```

in place of `<f:form.radio property="color" value="{color}" />`, where {colors} is an array of AbstractValueObject.

The reason can be found in here:
https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Property/TypeConverter/PersistentObjectConverter.php

The annotation in the header says:

> - If the input is string, it is assumed to be a UID. Then, the object is fetched from persistence.
> - ...
> - If the input has NO identity property, but additional properties, we create a new object and return it.

A ValueObject has no identity by definition. So the only way to add it without creating a new one is by passing the UID to the property mapper as a string parameter.